# Dates are not increasing how they should when I drag a pattern down a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to fill a column with dates and times. My time increments by hours. After 24 hours my date increases to the next. For some reason every 50 th cell or so the hours is thrown off by +- 1, 2, or 3 seconds. This is causing an issue for me because I am using this column as part of a match function I need to use in another workbook (I am using index match in another workbook). I am using the drag down "+" sign you get when you hover over the bottom right corner of the cell to generate the dates going down my column.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

If A1 has your start date and time, put this formula in A2 and copy all the way down. This formula will round to the nearest hour.

`=MROUND(A1,"1:00")+1/24`